# TextView with wrap_content height obscured by ListView below it

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout

I am not seeing my "Hello World" textview.
The listview, which I populate with elements, is all that shows.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    tools:context="lister.quantumproductions.com.lister.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_above="@+id/recipe_list_view"></TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loadListView();
    }

    private void loadListView() {
        mListView = findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_view);
        final ArrayList<Recipe> recipes = Recipe.getRecipesFromFile("recipes.json", this);

        RecipeAdapter a = new RecipeAdapter(this, recipes);
        mListView.setAdapter(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ListView fills the entire screen, and then you say that the TextView should be above the ListView, which makes it appear outside the screen, so it's not visible.

You need to invert the dependency.

So instead of the TextView being above the ListView, the ListView should be below the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

RelativeLayout causes the last item covers the previous one if it has match_parent width and height. Change the order or use LinearLayout instead of.

Answer (score 1):

you can use LinearLayout as the parent with Vertical Orientation it will work perfectly:-

I have corrected your xml code , use this code it works

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="lister.quantumproductions.com.lister.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_above="@+id/recipe_list_view"></TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/recipe_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

it will work and both textview and listview will be shown .

incase you want to use relative layout only just make listview also wrap_content

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
tools:context="lister.quantumproductions.com.lister.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recipe_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"></TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/recipe_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/recipe_text_view"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"></TextView>

<ListView
    android:layout_below="@id/text_view"
    android:id="@+id/recipe_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
```